# Issue with login into a wesite using python

Tags: python-2.7

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib, webbrowser

username = 'Firstname.lastname'
password = 'Password'
url = 'https://www.myhcl.com/Login/home.aspx'
webbrowser.open(url, new=1, autoraise=1)
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'txtUserID' : username, 'txtPassword' :      
password})
opener.open('https://www.myhcl.com/Login/home.aspx', login_data)
resp = opener.open('https://www.myhcl.com/Login/home.aspx')
print resp
webbrowser.open(url, new=1, autoraise=1)
#webbrowser.open_new('https://www.myhcl.com/Login/home.aspx')
```

By running this code web page opens, but fails to login to the page.

Comment: I look at the website and the form send more param than userid and password. They send `__EVENTTARGET`, `__EVENTARGUMENT`, `__VIEWSTATE`, `__EVENTVALIDATION`, `hddScrnResln`, `` hddBkgImage, `txtUserID`, `txtPassword`, `ddlDomain`, `btnSubmit.x` and `btnSubmit.y`

Comment: but it takes only two arguments login id and password while login

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is creating a cookie and refreshing the page. Even though the page shows few fields the cookie it creates may need other hidden data. The best way to do this would probably be with [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) in conjunction with any browser (Firefox is pretty popular) or a headless one like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

I also see that the login uses javascript opposed to the conventional submit tag. Selenium can interact with elements directly just like a user would.

Comment: Is it possible guess other hidden data?

Comment: Just track the cookies in your browser when you login and watch what it saves